# Smart number of decimals in ggplot facet axis labels

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a faceted `ggplot` like so:

```
library(ggplot2)
grid <- seq(-10,10,length.out=1000)
df <- data.frame(x=rep(grid,2),y=c(grid^2,100+grid^2/100000000),group=rep(c(1,2),each=length(grid)))
ggplot(df,aes(x,y)) + geom_line() + facet_wrap(~group,scales='free')
```

Problem is that the y-axes values for group 2 are all identical because they only differ in the 6-7th decimal. So I tried

```
fmt <- function(){
  function(x) format(x,nsmall = 7,scientific = FALSE)
}
ggplot(df,aes(x,y)) + geom_line() + facet_wrap(~group,scales='free') + scale_y_continuous(labels = fmt())
```

but that adds a lot of unnecessary decimals for the first group (duh!).

Is there any way to make `ggplot` show however many decimal places are necessary for the values on the y-axis to all be different for all facets? Or is doing this manually with `gridExtra` my best bet here?

Comment: I guess this is similar but perhaps not identical: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11585954/varying-axis-labels-formatter-per-facet-in-ggplot-r

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
fmt <- function(){
  function(x) {
    d <- log10(min(diff(x)))
    if(d < 0) format(x,nsmall = abs(round(d)),scientific = FALSE) else x
  }
}
ggplot(df,aes(x,y)) + geom_line() + 
    facet_wrap(~group,scales='free') + scale_y_continuous(labels = fmt())
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent! For more general setting such as mine it might make sense to make the third line `d <- log10(min(diff(x),na.rm=TRUE))` so it doesn't trip over missing values.

Comment: @RoyalTS There shouldn't be any missing values in `x`.

Comment: In my reproducible example that's true. But in real-world datasets such as mine, there may well be `NA`s and these will mess up your solution because if there are that's what `d` will be.

Comment: Umm, no. Non of your axis breaks should be `NA` and `x` are the axis breaks.

Comment: Huh. If I don't put the `na.rm=TRUE` in there I get `Error:  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed`.

Comment: Can you add `print(x)` at the top of the function and check these values?

Comment: A sample (sorry about the shitty formatting):

[1]    NA -1550 -1525 -1500    NA
[1] -1486.8 -1486.7 -1486.6 -1486.5 -1486.4 -1486.3
[1]        NA -1486.285 -1486.285 -1486.285

Comment: That surprises me. Well, if it works with `na.rm=TRUE` that's not a real problem.