# Annotate x-axis with N in faceted plot, but preserve empty facets

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I asked a question yesterday about [annotating the x-axis with N in a faceted plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39006840/annotate-x-axis-with-n-in-faceted-plot) using a minimal example that turns out to be too simple, relative to my real problem. The answer given there works in the case of complete data, but if you have missing facets you would like to preserve, the combination of `facet_wrap` options `drop=FALSE` and `scales="free_x"` triggers an error: `"Error in if (zero_range(from) || zero_range(to)) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed"`

Here is a new, less-minimal example. The goal here is to produce a large graph with two panels using `grid.arrange`; the first showing absolute values over time by treatment group; the second showing the change from baseline over time by treatment group. In the second panel, we need a blank facet when vis=1.

```
# setup
library(ggplot2)
library(plyr)
library(gridExtra)

trt      <- factor(rep(LETTERS[1:2],150),ordered=TRUE)
vis      <- factor(c(rep(1,150),rep(2,100),rep(3,50)),ordered=TRUE)
id       <- c(c(1:150),c(1:100),c(1:50))
val      <- rnorm(300)
data     <- data.frame(id,trt,vis,val)
base     <- with(subset(data,vis==1),data.frame(id,trt,baseval=val))
data     <- merge(data,base,by="id")
data     <- transform(data,chg=ifelse(vis==1,NA,val-baseval))
data.sum <- ddply(data, .(vis, trt), summarise, N=length(na.omit(val)))
data     <- merge(data,data.sum)
data     <- transform(data, trtN=paste(trt,N,sep="\n"))
mytheme  <- theme_bw() + theme(panel.margin = unit(0, "lines"), strip.background = element_blank())

# no missing facets
plot.a   <- ggplot(data) + geom_boxplot(aes(x=trtN,y=val,group=trt,colour=trt), show.legend=FALSE) +
            facet_wrap(~ vis, drop=FALSE, switch="x", nrow=1, scales="free_x") +
            labs(x="Visit") + mytheme
# first facet should be blank
plot.b   <- ggplot(data) + geom_boxplot(aes(x=trtN,y=chg,group=trt,colour=trt), show.legend=FALSE) +
            facet_wrap(~ vis, drop=FALSE, switch="x", nrow=1, scales="free_x") +
            labs(x="Visit") + mytheme

grid.arrange(plot.a,plot.b,nrow=2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a blank layer to draw all the facets in your second plot.  The key is that you need a variable that exists for every level of `vis` to use as your `y` variable.  In your case you can simply use the variable you used in your first plot.

```
ggplot(data) + 
    geom_boxplot(aes(x = trtN, y = chg, group = trt, colour = trt), show.legend = FALSE) +
    geom_blank(aes(x = trtN, y = val)) +
    facet_wrap(~ vis, switch = "x", nrow = 1, scales = "free_x") +
    labs(x="Visit") + mytheme
```

[image]

If your variables have different ranges, you can set the y limits using the overall min and max of your boxplot y variable.

`+ scale_y_continuous(limits = c(min(data$chg, na.rm = TRUE), max(data$chg, na.rm = TRUE)))`

Comment: The one (nonfatal) problem in this solution is that when val has a larger range than chg, the y-axis is notably scaled to val rather than chg. But I'm pretty close.

Comment: That's easily addressed by setting the limits of the y axis based on the range of chg.

Comment: Agreed - what's the rule used by the default? max(chg), min(chg) +/- some constant?

Comment: @ErinMcJ I think the default limits actually are the min and max of the variable plus the defaults given in `expand`.  So setting the limits to the max and min should be all you need to do.  You can easily check this by making a simple plot and then manually setting the limits and comparing plots and/or looking directly at the `ggplot_build` output.