# Specifying different x-tick labels for two facet groups in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot, facet

I have boxplots representing results of two methods, each with two validation approaches and three scenarios, to be plotted using ggplot2. Everything works fine, but I want to change the x-axis tick label to differentiate between the type of technique used in each group.

I used the following code:

```
data <- read.csv("results.csv", header = TRUE, sep=',')

ggplot() + 
  geom_boxplot(data = data, aes(x = Validation, y = Accuracy, fill = Scenario)) +
  facet_wrap(~ Method) +
  labs(fill = "")
```

where the structure of my data is as follows:

```
Method        Validation        Scenario       Accuracy
-------------------------------------------------------
Method 1      Iterations        Scenario 1     0.90
Method 1      Iterations        Scenario 2     0.80
Method 1      Iterations        Scenario 3     0.86
Method 1      Recursive         Scenario 2     0.82
Method 2      Iterations        Scenario 1     0.69
Method 2      Recursive         Scenario 3     0.75
```

and got the following plot:

[image]

I just want to change the first x-tick label (**Iterations**) in Method 1 and Method 2 into *100-iterations* and *10-iterations*, respectively.

I tried to add this code but that changes the labels for both groups.

```
+ scale_x_discrete(name = "Validation", 
                   labels = c("100-iterations", "Recursive", 
                              "10-iterations", "Recursive")) +
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The ggplot package's facet options were not designed for varying axis labels / scales across facets (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11585954/varying-axis-labels-formatter-per-facet-in-ggplot-r) for a detailed explanation), but one work around in this instance would be to vary the underlying x-axis variable's values for different facets, & set `scales = "free_x"` in `facet_wrap()` so that only the relevant values are shown in each facet's x-axis:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

ggplot(data %>%
         mutate(Validation = case_when(Validation == "Recursive" ~ "Recursive",
                                       Method == "Method 1" ~ "100-iterations",
                                       TRUE ~ "10-iterations")),
       aes(x = Validation, y = Accuracy, fill = Scenario)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  facet_wrap(~ Method, scales = "free_x")
```

[image: plot]

Data:

```
set.seed(1)
data <- data.frame(
  Method = rep(c("Method 1", "Method 2"), each = 100),
  Validation = rep(c("Iterations", "Recursive"), times = 100),
  Scenario = sample(c("Scenario 1", "Scenario 2", "Scenario 3"), 200, replace = TRUE),
  Accuracy = runif(200)
)
```

Comment: great answer. For this case the ordering works fine, but in other cases you may need to factor the x-axis variable to finely control order. eg to reverse the order: `mutate(Validation = factor(Validation, levels = c("Recursive", "10-iterations", "100-iterations"))`