# Facet_wrap: conditional formatting based on label_value?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

For some of my charts I would like to change the formatting of the numbers on the x axis for each facet conditionally on the label of the facet e.g. based on the order of magnitude (e.g. k, M, B etc.).

In the example below with the `mtcars` data, I would like the facet with `gear==3` to keep the original number, with `gear==4` create a "k" format and with `gear==5` an "M" format. So that the two latter would be expressed in thousands and millions respectively.

Is is possible to use the `label_value` from the `labeller` to apply conditionally a format/function?

```
library(tidyverse)

d<-mtcars%>%mutate(mpg2=ifelse(gear==5,mpg*1000000,mpg))

ggplot(d) +
      geom_point(aes(mpg2, cyl)) +
      facet_wrap(~ gear, scales = "free")+
      scale_x_continuous(name = NULL,  labels = function(l) {
          return(paste0(round(l / 1000, 1), "K"))
      })
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to make the gear change the format, but you could certainly make different scales of numbers be displayed differently for all facets...  `ggplot(d) + geom_point(aes(mpg2, cyl)) + facet_wrap(~ gear, scales = "free") + scale_x_continuous(name = NULL,  labels = function(l) { scaled = case_when(l > 1E6  ~ paste0(formatC(l/1E6, digits = 0, big.mark = ",", format = "f"), "M"),  l > 1E3   ~ paste0(formatC(l/1E3, digits = 0, big.mark = ",", format = "f"), "K"),
                       TRUE ~ paste0(l))
    return(scaled)
  })`

Comment: @JonSpring I think that qualifies as a pretty good answer, why not post it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking to allow the scale formatting to vary according the value, here's a way using `dplyr::case_when`. (I don't know how to show the same numbers differently based on the facet, though.)

#### Edit to show wider range in example:

```
d <- mtcars %>% mutate(mpg2 = mpg ^ gear / carb)


ggplot(d) +
  geom_point(aes(mpg2, cyl)) +
  facet_wrap(~ gear, scales = "free")+
  scale_x_continuous(name = NULL,  trans = "log2", labels = function(l) {
     scaled = case_when(l >= 1E6 ~ paste0(formatC(l/1E6, digits = 0, big.mark = ",", format = "f"), "M"),
                        l >= 1E3 ~ paste0(formatC(l/1E3, digits = 0, big.mark = ",", format = "f"), "K"),
                        TRUE     ~ paste0(l))
     return(scaled)
})
```

[image]

I think it works pretty well.

If you need specific control over the labeling by facet, you might consider either faking the facet axis text with `geom_text(aes(label = your_preferred_label))` and turning clipping off in `coord_` so you can put text outside the plot range, or (more simply) combining plots with `patchwork` or `cowplot`. I'm not aware of a way to make the labeller itself aware of facet info.

Comment: It's a good start that would do in most use cases. but imagine that you have a range of 900 to 15000 then it would result

Comment: Updated my answer to show what happens when you have a range across scales like you mention.

Comment: In a way that could be perceived as inconsistent, likewise in cases where the order of magnitude is the same but the unit is different (e.g. currencies) this approach wouldn't work.  I am looking for how toread the labeller's label_value in such a way that I can use it in the labels as a condition, to avoid entering into solutions based on grobs.

Comment: I will keep it open a little more to see whether someone can clarify the "reading label_value" bit, but it helps me already for many of my charts

Comment: Here's some discussion on why this is not built into ggplot2:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11585954/varying-axis-labels-formatter-per-facet-in-ggplot-r    and    https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/1613